# Cygwin 環境の OpenGL において音声ファイルを再生したい

Tags: opengl, cygwin

openglでゲーム制作を行っているのですが，以下のようなエラーが出てしまい実行できません．
PlaySoundはWindows固有の関数なので使えないのでしょうか？また，ほかにopenglでwavファイルを流す方法があれば教えていただきたいです．

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/nimon/AppData/Local/Temp/cch6fo9W.o:shadowHunter.c:(.text+0x1080): `_imp__PlaySoundA@12' に対する定義されていない参照です
collect2: エラー: ld はステータス 1 で終了しました
make: *** [Makefile:31: ShadowHunter.exe] エラー 1
```

実行したプログラムのソースコードは以下です．

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
int main(){
PlaySound(TEXT("sample.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> #pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
> ```

この記述はMicrosoft Visual C++独自の書式であり、他の環境では使えません。Windowsで資料を参照しながら開発を行うなら、素直に標準コンパイラであるVisual C++を使用することをお勧めします。Cygwinを利用するのは標準コンパイラを理解してからの方が混乱が少ないでしょう。

なお、gccでは`-lwinmm`と指定することになりそうです。

---

> openglでwavファイルを流す方法があれば教えていただきたいです．

[OpenGL](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL)はグラフィックスライブラリであり、音声は扱えないはずです。